# How to make a square array dataset on polar stereo-graphic projection from general lat-lon gridded netCDF dataset?

Tags: python, arrays, matplotlib, netcdf, cartopy

I would like to convert shape of dataset from general lat-lon girdded netCDF dataset to a square array on the polar stereographic projection for making training dataset for a deep learning project (Figure 1 might help you understand the question). However, I still can't figure out how to do this.. it's been over a month.

[Format of dataset I have and desired shape of the dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/COMsj.jpg)
[image: pix1]

First I tried making a polar stereographic plot using cartopy and matplotlib and extract array from it. So I was able to make this plot (figure 2) but extracting the square array from the figure was impossible.

I thought about just making image dataset by saving generate plots but exact number of the dataset is very important so I could not just use image dataset.

[A heatmap of geopotential height on the polar stereographic projection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gYg0K.png)
[image: pix2]

I would greatly apprecitate for providing any ideas for this problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting between projections using pyproj in Pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39620105/converting-between-projections-using-pyproj-in-pandas-dataframe)